# json changes the order of elements

Tags: android, json, servlets

I am trying to send a list of objects from an android mobile phone app to a j2ee webserver.
I create json objects and then put the objects into an jsonarray(in an order) and then send it. I am able to receive the jsonarray on the server, obtain the objects individually too, but the order of how I inserted the objects into the jsonarray is different compared to the order present in the received array. The order of elements plays a crucial role in my data processing. Could somebody please tell me a workaround for this.

Thanks,
raqz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the issue by maintaining an index id element. so i fetch the elements based on the id.